# trying to change background image depending on weather condition in jQuery. also limit data to 6

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('button').on("click", function(){
  var location = $('#location').val();

  $("#show-weather").html("Temperature & Humidity for " + location + ".");
    $.ajax({
      url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + location + '&units=metric&APPID=3f196ebe1a8f3f884f4a32af14171ea6',
      type:"GET",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true,

      //here is where I tried to limit JSON data but no luck. it worked in angular but not in jQuery

      data: {limit: 6},
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data.main.temp);
        $("#main-temp").html(data.main.temp * (9/5) + 32 + ' &#176' + " F");
        $('#main-humidity').html(data.main.humidity  + " &#37");
        $('#main-description').html(data.weather[0].description);
      },
      error: function(){
          alert("Enter a city!");
      }
    });
    // clears input
    $('#location').val("");

      //here is where I was trying to change background image depending on weather condition but with no luck. 

    if($('#main-description').is(':contains("clear")')){
      $('body').css('background-image','url("img/clear.jpg")');
    }

  });
```

I am not sure what I am missing but I am definitely missing something . Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: One thing that's definitely missing is a clear statement of what the problem you're trying to solve is.  "No luck" doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: if($('#main-description').is(':contains("clear")')){
      $('body').css('background-image','url("img/clear.jpg")');
    }

Comment: this is where I was trying to add the code for changing background image depending on weather description.

Comment: I see that, yes.  Were there error messages? Did your ajax fail to load? Did it load but with unexpected data?  Did you get the correct data but the image didn't display correctly?   Something else? The question needs to have a clear problem statement, not just code with "it didn't work please help".

Comment: sorry, I need to get more specific I understand now. So the code works and everything appears on the browser, the temp, description and humidity all appear. I want to change the background image to what the weather description is that day. so if description of day is "clear sky" the add a clear image and if "rain" then add a rain image.

Comment: The code you have looks like it should work just fine for that (assuming the image path is correct).  Did it not work? Are you asking how to add more conditions besides 'clear'? What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: I put "clear" because the description that came up for that city came up "clear sky".  But even with that the background image didn't change. So something is wrong with that :contains code.